# CoreData one-to-many using just one Entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I have two entities Parent and Child(relationship between - "children", inverse - "parent") it's simple get children of concrete parent, see code below:

```
Parent *parent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Child" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(parent == %@)", parent]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"results :%@", results);
```

Yes, of course, I can get children without *NSFetchRequest*, but in my case I have to do that in this way;
Okay, and my trouble is that I have only ONE entity, for example "Parent"(relationship - "parents", inverse - "parents");
and One Parent has 3 other parents;
How to get all parents concrete parent; I try to do this:

```
Parent *parent = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

[request setSortDescriptors:@[sort]];

[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(parents == %@)", parent]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"results :%@", results);
```

But my program program crashes:
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'**

Comment: Show an image of your model (at least the entity). You should have 2 relationships which are inverses, what are both names?

Comment: Pretty confusing, a screenshot of the data model would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you have only one entity, you need to define *two relationships*:

- "parent" as to-one relationship from the entity to itself, and
- "children" as to-many relationship from the entity to itself

and make them inverse relationships of each other. Then

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(parent == %@)", parent]
```

should work as expected.

Comment: Martin, what do you think about many-to-many relationship in Core Data? I thought about, and now I'm using many-to-many relationship; For better understanding imagine facebook friends, every friend can be friend for a lot of users and he can has a lot of friends; I'm trying to do this using one entity and after get friends concrete user using NSFetchRequest

Comment: @O.Daniel: I have no problems with many-to-many relationships. What is your question?

Comment: @O.Daniel: I do not understand the last part: *"after get friends concrete user using NSFetchRequest"*

Comment: sorry) ok, again) imagine facebook, on your friend's profile are some his friends, and you want to display them; I mean you display concrete user's friends and I want to do this using NSFetchRequest; I hope this is better explanation;

Comment: @O.Daniel: You can do that with a predicate like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY friends == %@", person]` .

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work; After execution of fetch request array is empty;